# Horizontal Leader Board based on organisation

Tags: excel-formula, lookup, ranking

I am trying to work out the ranking of top 3 users at different organisations and have the data presented horizontally for each user so it can be inputted into our email system to personalise emails.

I am able to create a ranking vertically but I am not sure how to get the formula to rank based on organisation and return value across.

Here is what I need to have in the end:

```
Name    Organisation    Usage   First   Second  Third
User 1  Organisation 1  8   User 3  User 5  User 2
User 2  Organisation 1  10  User 3  User 5  User 2
User 3  Organisation 1  222 User 3  User 5  User 2
User 4  Organisation 1  1   User 3  User 5  User 2
User 5  Organisation 1  14  User 3  User 5  User 2
User 1  Organisation 2  215 User 4  User 1  User 5
User 2  Organisation 2  18  User 4  User 1  User 5
User 3  Organisation 2  12  User 4  User 1  User 5
User 4  Organisation 2  310 User 4  User 1  User 5
User 5  Organisation 2  161 User 4  User 1  User 5
```

I can return a ranking vertically one organisation at a time using

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$2:$C$6=LARGE($C$2:$C$6,ROWS(H$1:H1)))*(COUNTIF(H$1:H1,$A$2:$A$6)=0),),0))
```

If someone could help me run this formula based on each organisation and horizontally that would be fantastic!

Thanks,

Sarah.

Comment: Can there be duplicates for `Usage`?

Comment: Yes, some users may have  the same usage, but I'm just looking to pull out the top three, if two are the same I am happy to rank them in alphabetical order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Non-Empty Usage Solution:

Assuming your data starts in `A1` Like so:

```
    A       B               C       D       E       F
 ---------------------------------------------------------
1 | Name    Organisation    Usage   First   Second  Third
2 | User 1  Organisation 1  8       User 3  User 5  User 2
3 | User 2  Organisation 1  10      User 3  User 5  User 2
4 | User 3  Organisation 1  222     User 3  User 5  User 2
5 | User 4  Organisation 1  1       User 3  User 5  User 2
6 | User 5  Organisation 1  14      User 3  User 5  User 2
7 | User 1  Organisation 2  215     User 4  User 1  User 5
8 | User 2  Organisation 2  18      User 4  User 1  User 5
9 | User 3  Organisation 2  12      User 4  User 1  User 5
10| User 4  Organisation 2  310     User 4  User 1  User 5
11| User 5  Organisation 2  161     User 4  User 1  User 5
```

You can change your formula starting in `D2` to:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$2:$C$11=LARGE(($B$2:$B$11=$B2)*$C$2:$C$11,COLUMNS($C2:C2)))*(COUNTIF($C2:C2,$A$2:$A$11)=0),),0))
```

What I changed:

1. Added `($B$2:$B$11=$B2)` inside the `LARGE` which multiplies all the Usage values for other organizations by `0`.  Which then won't be picked up by the `LARGE` function.
2. Changed the `ROWS(H$1:H1)` to `COLUMNS($C2:C2)` so you can rank horizontally
3. I also changed the cell references to the entire dataset rows 2 to 11

#### Solution with possible empty Usage:

If the Usage is empty (*for all users in the same organization*) and you desire the First, Second, and Third column to be blank then also, like so:

```
    A       B               C       D       E       F
 ---------------------------------------------------------
1 | Name    Organisation    Usage   First   Second  Third
2 | User 1  Organisation 1  8       User 3  User 5  User 2
3 | User 2  Organisation 1  10      User 3  User 5  User 2
4 | User 3  Organisation 1  222     User 3  User 5  User 2
5 | User 4  Organisation 1  1       User 3  User 5  User 2
6 | User 5  Organisation 1  14      User 3  User 5  User 2
7 | User 1  Organisation 2          
8 | User 2  Organisation 2        
9 | User 3  Organisation 2         
10| User 4  Organisation 2          
11| User 5  Organisation 2
```

We can accomplish this by checking if the entire Usage for the Organization is 0.  Then we can blank out all the ranks for that Organization.

1. To check if the sum of the usages for the organization is 0 we can use `SUMPRODUCT:`  So for cell `D2` that would look like:

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$11)*($B$2:$B$11=$B2))=0
   ```
2. Then we can just wrap an `IF` around everything and blank it if the above statement returns true.  So our final formula would look like:

   ```
   =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$11)*($B$2:$B$11=$B2))=0,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$2:$C$11=LARGE(($B$2:$B$11=$B2)*$C$2:$C$11,COLUMNS($C2:C2)))*(COUNTIF($C2:C2,$A$2:$A$11)=0),),0)))
                                                   ^^ Throw whatever you want in there
   ```

Now if you want the text to say anything else, just put that text inside the quotes for the `TRUE` condition of the `IF` statement.

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic, it works great! The only slight issue is that for organisations where there is no 'Usage' yet it is returning the name of the first user? Is there a way to add a default blank option where the number of users with usage has run out? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sarah.Frances So you are saying if the `Usage` column is blank you want the user to also be blank?

Comment: Yes or allow the option for an alternative text so the auto-populated leaderboard in the email lets the user know no one has started yet.

Comment: @Sarah.Frances Alright I (hopefully) have added that